# Wav format audio file is not working in windows Edge browser and safari (windows and ios)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, wav

I have used `<embed>` Tag for Internet Explorer and `<audio>` Tag for other browsers, which works fine for IE, Firefox and Chrome. However, it's not working in Safari and Edge browsers. Following are the code snippets :

```
<embed src = "'+Wavlocation+'" hidden="true" autostart="true" name="Nam" id="Nam" enablejavascript="true" />
<audio autoplay>  
    <source src = "'+Wavlocation+'" type="audio/wav" name="Nam" id="Nam"  >     
</audio>
```

Comment: perhaps edge and safari are picky about `</audo>` not being `</audio>` ... or the fact that you haven't closed the `<embed` tag - try *valid* HTML at least

Comment: It was a typing error, corrected here. In actual code the tags are correctly closed and used the correct spelling thats why its working in three browsers mention above.       Thanks